# How to serve two folders (React build files) on one website on IIS?

Tags: reactjs, windows, iis, static, react-router

I have IIS web server, and I am using the IP address and :80 port to serve the website.

I have two applications. One of them should be served on '/' route, and another one should be accessible on '/admin' route.

I tried multiple advices about "how to serve two websites on one IP and Port", but they do not help me. I also created virtual directory with static files, but still cannot access the second app on '/admin' route

Can you please give me recommendations what do I need to add to "web.config" to make it work. I want the "app1" be on home route, that it, '/', and "app2" be on the "/admin" route, so

111.111.11.11/ - this is "app1"

111.111.11.11/about - this is still "app1"

111.111.11.11/admin - and when the use goes to admin, this is "app2"

Answer (score 1):

First, create child application or virtual directory under the mail application. give full access control isur and iis_iusrs.

Convert all absolute links to relative ones. Base tag works only for relative URLs. The bare minimum plain HTML example.

```
<img src="/assets/logo.svg"/> to <img src="./assets/logo.svg"/>
```

Add  in your index.html. This tag should be placed in the ... before any other element that uses URLs. The best place to put it right above the ... in the index.html

```
    <head>
  ...
  <base href="%PUBLIC_URL%/">
  <title>React App</title>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

[image]

Regards,
Jalpa

Comment: Could you please tell me, what is "give full access control isur and iis_iusrs" - I am newbie at IIS.

Comment: 1)open site folder and right click on and select properties. 2)select the security tab and select edit and add iusr and iis_iusrs users and provide permission to that user to access the site folder.[image link](https://i.postimg.cc/cChvvCYg/per.jpg)

Comment: https://ibb.co/jTF40f5 - this is a structure which I use. So, Default Web Site - this is a one folder, and then I want on this URL "/admin" to serve another folder.

Comment: https://ibb.co/zs3xRmH - and this is how my Application Pool section is structured

Comment: You need to give permission to both site folders.

Comment: Still does not work, I added these 2 folders + Network Service and Local Service

Comment: Even when I go to <SOME_IP>/admin, it serves index.html file from <SOME_IP>

Comment: could you share a snapshot of browser and permission?

Comment: could you share your rewrite rule?

Comment: You could use this rule to avoid rewriting the app2 to index of app1 in your rule.<rule name="DynamicContent"> 
    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(.*)/app2(.*)" negate="true" /> 
    </conditions> 
    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
                    <match url="(.*)" /> 
    </rule>