# IIS: Host 2 SPAs under the same site

Tags: angular, reactjs, iis, deployment

Unfortunately i am working in a project where as a temporary solution we want to have 2 different SPAs one written in Angular and one in React simultaneously released in the same server under the same dns and port.

Basically one is the rewrite of the other and until we migrate all the pages from Angular to React we have to have both up and running.

Currently Angular application is deployed is IIS and by using the rewrite module we can utilize Angular router.

[image]

To give you a bit more context lets say that the angular app has 3 pages.

And that the first react release will have one of them migrated over.

That means that when the user is requesting  **"example/page1"** has to go to the angular app and when is navigating to **example/page2** has to go to react app.

My initial thought is that

1) i could put the 2 projects under the same folder which will be the physical path of the site.

[image]

2) I could create a web.config which in there i will add the rules for rewriting and specifying the site/bundles that should return to the user's browser.

And the web.config would be something like

```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Default React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/react/index.html" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="React Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="page2" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/react/index.html" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Angular Routes" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="page1" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/angular/index.html" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Unfortunately this solution makes me have to change a bunch of stuff in the projects index.html.

Does anybody know a better solution or knows if that would even work, a proxy maybe ??

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular**

You need to build you application using `--base-href` which will help you to make root of your application.

As stated in AngularCLI [documentation](https://angular.io/cli/build)

> `--base-href` Base url for the application being built.

e.g. `ng build --prod --base-href /directory-name/` where `directory-name` is *angular* in your scenario.

**React**

Setting the `basename` attribute on the `<Router />` component tells React Router that the app will be served from a subdirectory.

```
<Router basename={'/directory-name'}>
  <Route path='/' component={Home} />
  {/* … */}
</Router>
```

where `directory-name` is *react* in your scenario.

---

Now once you're done setting up your base routes in your applications, you can bind `Site2 - AngularApp` with `example/angular` and `Site3 - ReactApp` with `example/react` directories.

Answer (score 0):

To implement your requirement you could use the URL rewrite rule if you hosted all site separately.

or if you want to host the 2 another site as an application then you just need to set the build path of the site in application path and assign the name of the application. (for the angular after building the app it will create the dist folder use that as an application path)

[image]

[image]

[image]

You could refer this link for more deatil:

[How to serve two folders (React build files) on one website on IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56007384/how-to-serve-two-folders-react-build-files-on-one-website-on-iis/56018060#56018060)

Comment: Thank you for the response , how could i remove the "myapp2" part of the url ?  I would ideally would like to keep my urls agnostic in the client's browser.Thanks

Comment: @k.explorer you could use page1 or page 2 or any other name of the application. it is not necessary to use the app1 or app2

Comment: So can i change somehow the virtual directory value , cause from the advanced settings window this is not possible ?

Comment: no, you can not change the name of virtual directory or application. you need to remove the old one and gain try to add new with the new name.